# Construct bijections $f_1 : ((0,1)\times(2,3)) \rightarrow (0,2)\times(5,6)$ and $f_2 : (\mathbb{Z}\times[0,1))\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to construct two bijections:
$$f_1 : ((0,1)\times(2,3)) \rightarrow (0,2)\times(5,6)$$
$$f_2 : (\mathbb{Z}\times[0,1))\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
I know what bijection means and all conditions that functions have to fulfill in order to be bijective, but I have no idea how should I 'construct' them. I thought of drawing graphs of each set from function $f_1$, but it does not help me to do further steps.
It would be nice if you could show me step-by-step how it should be done.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the word "construct". If you were just asked to *find* the bijections, would you know what to do?

Comment: I know that I should somehow find functions which fit these sets, but how can I do it if not by guessing?

Comment: Have you *tried* just "guessing"? This is not a follow-a- method exercise, it's just a check question to make sure you have understood what a bijection is.

Comment: I tried to transform $f_1 : ((0,1)\times(2,3)) \rightarrow (0,2)\times(5,6)$ into $f_1 : A \rightarrow B$, where $A : (0,1)\rightarrow (2,3)$ and $B : (0,2)\rightarrow (5,6)$ and then find functions fitting both sets, but I could not do that.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you make just a function that maps (0,1) bijectively to (2,3)?

Comment: I thought that it would be $f(x) = x+2$ for $(0,1)\rightarrow (2,3)$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+5$ for $(0,2)\rightarrow (5,6)$, but I am not sure whether it is what I am looking for.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I got an idea for $f_1$, which is $f(a,b) = (2a, b+3)$ and I guess it might be a good answer, but for $f_2$ I have still no clue how to write it as a function. I think about it as a graph, which for each $\mathbb{Z}$ goes up vertically in range $[0, x)$ and down (for negative values) in range $(x, 0]$, but I can not find any formula.

Comment: x @whiskeyo: $f_1(a,b)=(2a,b+3)$ is indeed a good bijection from $(0,1)\times(2,3)$ to $(0,2)\times(5,6)$. (Sorry for suggesting you would need a function $(0,1)\to(2,3)$. I quoted it from your comment where I hadn't noticed you were splitting it the wrong way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f_2$,The usual euclidean product of sets may be a little confusing here.

Try thinking of "$\mathbb{Z}\times[0,1)$" as the set "To each integer, assign an interval from 0 to 1." Then $f_2(x,t) = x+t$ is a bijection to $\mathbb{R}$, where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the integer part of some real number, and $t\in[0,1)$ is the decimal part of that number.